# Macro hell: Platform-independent pointer to setjmp/sigsetjmp

Tags: c, macros, posix, iso, setjmp

I am writing multiplatform code which needs to use a pointer to setjmp/sigsetjmp. Normally that would be as simple as doing

```
#include <setjmp.h>
void * sigsetjmp_p = sigsetjmp;
```

However, ISO and POSIX state that setjmp/sigsetjmp can be defined as a macro, and indeed that is the case in my linux box. Here's an excerpt from `/usr/include/setjmp.h`:

```
# define sigsetjmp(env, savemask)       __sigsetjmp (env, savemask)
```

The problem is that, since I am not passing arguments to `sigsetjmp`, the macro doesn't expand and the plain `sigsetjmp` symbol is not defined in libc. I was hoping to be able to use some macro "black magic" to extract the "__sigsetjmp" name, but I have failed miserably so far.

Another option would be using  `__sigsetjmp` directly but this would imply checking the expansion for every supported platform, which I don't want to do (hence the reason of this question).

PS: I hate macros.

**Note:**

The reason for which I need this is a bit obscure, but to simplify it, let's say I want to perform pointer comparisons with it.

```
#include <setjmp.h>
int equals_sigsetjmp(void *p)
{
 void * sigsetjmp_p =  sigsetjmp;
 return p == sigsetjmp_p;
}
```

**Edit:**

Yes, yes. I know I shouldn't count on getting a pointer to `sigsetjmp` because it might not even be a function in certain platforms but **this doesn't solve my problem**.

In practice, all platforms I know of implement it as a function.

I can cope with the fact that, in a few years, I run into a case in which `sigsetjump` is not a function for certain platform. But what I wouldn't like to cope with is going through every supported platform and check `setjmp.h` for macro definitions, which is my only option right now.

I appreciate the references to standards but I would like to get a practical answer not a *purist* one.

Comment: Btw., casting a function pointer to a `void*` is also non-portable.

Comment: There is a real reason for this, but it is rather long to explain (it involves function wrapping). Trust me, I need that pointer :)

Comment: @larsmans true, I just wanted to provide a simplified example. Giving a proper type to p though doesn't change the problem.

Comment: Alas, `setjmp`/`sigsetjmp` is allowed to be a macro precisely because it may not be feasible to implement it as a function. It could expand to a bunch of `asm` commands, a builtin, or whatever else the implementation desires. You cannot count on getting a pointer to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this portably, as the standard explicitly forbids it (§7.13):

> It is unspecified whether `setjmp` is a macro or an identifier declared with external
>   linkage. **If a macro definition is suppressed in order to access an actual function** (...) **the behavior is undefined.**

To which POSIX adds that

> The `sigsetjmp()` function shall be **equivalent** to the `setjmp()` function

with some exceptions that are irrelevant here.

As for your remark

> all platforms I know of implement it as a function

In GCC, `setjmp` is a built-in, and I believe in Clang, so is `sigsetjmp`. (Though the C library might have a function version as well.)

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the standard. You are right, I shouldn't rely on the actual function but unfortunately I need to. And in practice it won't lead to undefined behavior for all the platforms we support.

Comment: @fons: if you have a limited set of platforms to support and you want to perform black magic, then the solution is to maintain a list of `#ifdef`s that handle the cases you're interested in. But beware that the behavior is still undefined "in practice" because a new version of the compiler or library may break your program. You're effectively tying yourself to a compiler version, library version, and a set of compiler flags that make your program work.

Comment: Can you show proof of `setjmp` being a builtin in GCC? I can clearly see it being declared as a function (without macros) in /usr/include/sejmp.h. `extern int setjmp (jmp_buf __env) __THROWNL;`

Comment: @fons: try replacing `setjmp` with `__builtin_setjmp`. Apparently, GNU libc provides a function `setjmp` as well, probably for other compilers.

Comment: OK, there is a builtin but setjmp is also a function, so the statement about setjmp being defined in all platforms still holds. I know I shouldn't rely on it but I really need to.

Comment: @fons: the statement does not hold until you check all platforms. I've got the feeling that you're solving the wrong problem, but without details of why you need this pointer comparison from hell, I can't say what the solution would be except a load of `#ifdef`s.

Comment: It's too long to explain, really. But you have helped a lot, I might have a cleaner solution now. Thanks!

Comment: @fons: final remark: if all you want to do is pointer comparisons, then there is a workaround, which is to use a dummy object to stand in for `sigsetjmp`. Of course, the side that produces the function pointers should use that as well.

Comment: Even built-in functions need prototypes.

Comment: @ams and, in many cases (I don't know about the particular case of setjmp) using a builtin results in calling a symbol provided by the compiler library (e.g. libgcc).

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
void my_sigsetjmp(sigjmp_buf env, int savesigs)
{
    sigsetjmp(env, savesigs);
}
```

Then use the address of &my_sigsetjmp

Answer (score -1):

For what you say you want, I would do something like:

```
#include <setjmp.h>
#ifdef sigsetjmp
#define AVOID_FUNCTION_MACRO /* expand to nothing */
int sigsetjmp AVOID_FUNCTION_MACRO (sigjmp_buf env, int savesigs) {
    log_fatal_error("Can't call sigsetjmp via pointer, its a macro!");
    abort();
}
#endif
```

This will give you a `sigsetjmp` function you can take the address of, but you can't actually call it...

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Wouldn't that code simply expand to `int sigsetjmp(sigjmp_buf env, int savesigs) { ... }` ? Then I could get the address of the `sigsetjmp` function we just defined, but it would be different to the address of `__sigsetjmp`,  which is what I want.

Comment: @fons: that is the idea.  The `__sigsetjmp` function is just one specific implementation of sigsetjmp -- other macro-based solutions do something different.  If sigsetjmp is a macro, you can't (in general) get a function pointer that you can call, as even if there is a function, it likely has massaged arguments (which is why the macro is needed).